# Cycles bugging on random frames

Tags: cycles-render-engine

Cycles is bugging on random frames.
Any ideas of what's causing this issue? You can clearly see the problem in this clip:
https://youtu.be/eo1iRQluigQ

Comment: this could happen if you don't bake your cloth simulation

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could happen if there are modifiers after your simulation modifier and the vertices get to close together to solve nicely. With more information we could pinpoint the problem better.

Comment: This helped!
There're MeshSequenceCache modifier + Subdivision modifier.

It seems that the problem is from the Subdivision modifier. Can you suggest a solution besides applying the subdivision?

Comment: You can make the initial simulation with less subdivisions (or in your case when you are using imported geometry use a decimate modiefier) or you can lessen the modifiers subdivisions. You must make sure that you are not getting any intersecting geometry in you simulation and also with the modifiers on.